# Extensions of solvable Groups and solvability in between...

Tags: group-theory, solvable-groups, group-extensions

I was trying to solve the following problem:

Let $G,K,H$ groups and $\text{φ}:G \rightarrow K, \text{ψ}: K \rightarrow H$  homomorfisms and $ker{\text{ψ}} \subseteq \text{φ}(G)$ . If $G,H$ are solvable, is K solvable?

I know generally that the class of solvable groups is closed to extensions. But how about that? Any hints?

Comment: Well $\ker \psi$ and ${\rm im}\, \psi$ are both solvable, so you can apply the result you know about solvable groups being closed under extension.

Comment: @DerekHolt      thank you for your help, I solved the problem!

Comment: @DerekHolt      I'm not sure about something.  How do we know that kerψ is a solvable group? Do homomorfisms retain the solvable property in general?

Comment: Yes, subgroups and quotient groups of solvable groups are solvable.